# filtering objects from nsmutablearray with a nsarray of string values

Tags: xcode, properties, filter, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a NSMutableArray called "scoreBoard" which has hundreds of objects with properties name,score,id

I also have a NSArray called "friends" with a list of strings

I want to scan all objects "id" from "scoreBoard" with NSArray "friends" and keep only the objects which property value id matches the list of "friends"

can anyone give me some directions?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    NSIndexSet *toRemove = [scoreBoard indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
         return [friends containsObject:obj.name];
    }];
    [scoreBoard removeObjectsAtIndexdes:toRemove];
```

Note this isn't optimally fast. You might also want to look at `[NSMutableArray filterUsingPredicate:]` although `NSPredicate` isn't my preference.